# How to decompress Hadoop snappy compressed file in Java

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, parquet, snappy

We are compressing Flink job S3 output using Hadoop Parquet+Snappy compression.

```
AvroParquetWriter.<T>builder(out)
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                .withDataModel(dataModel)
                .build();
```

Now we tried to use Hadoop SnappyDecompressor/Snappy-java dependency in an Ec2 Java service to decompress this file but both returning following exception :

**"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.decompressBytesDirect()'"** .

Please let us know what is the correct way to decompress these files in a Java Ec2 service.

```
    final SnappyDecompressor decompressor = new SnappyDecompressor();
    final byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(s3ObjectInputStream);
    decompressor.setInput(data, 0, data. Length);
    final byte[] uncompressed = new byte[10 * 1024 * 1024];
    decompressor.decompress(uncompressed, 0, data.length);

    final SnappyInputStream snappyInputStream = new SnappyInputStream(s3ObjectInputStream);
    final List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(snappyInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```